# Angular form fails to submit

Tags: angular

I have a form like this (simplified):

```
<form [action]='endpoint' method="post" (submit)="submitConfirmation($event)">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And in the controller:

```
submitConfirmation(event) {}
```

When I click the submit button, the method `submitConfirmation` runs but the form doesn't submit! I've tried half a hundred different combinations and the only way I can make it submit is by doing this:

```
<form [action]='endpoint' method="post" #confirmForm (ngSubmit)="submitConfirmation($event)">
  <button type="submit" (click)="confirmForm.submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Which is not something I've seen anywhere in the documentation... What is going here? All I really want to do is control whether the form gets submitted or not (eg. `event.preventDefault()` or `return false`) but nothing works the way it's supposed to!

Comment: I have tried your first example and it is showing me logs when I press submit.

Comment: @SunnyParekh Yes, when I submit the form the `submitConfirmation()` method is definitely running, but the form itself does not submit.

Comment: and your `submitConfirmation()` function does what? You can ignore the action attribute. This is not a regular form. All the "magic" happens in your `submitConfirmation` function. You don't need to pass the $event to the function. It should be an empty params function. You don't need the click eventlistener on the button but you do need `(ngSubmit)="functionName()"`. button type can and should remain of type "submit".

Comment: @altu And that is exactly what I had before. Button `type="submit"` with no click handler. Form has `(ngSubmit)="submitConfirmation()"`. When I do that, the method runs but the form doesn't submit. I discovered I can force it to submit by passing in a reference to the form itself (`#confirmForm (ngSubmit)="submitConfirmation(confirmForm)"`) and then calling `confirmForm.submit()` manually but is this really how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Read again what I wrote

Comment: @altu I have read it, which part do you think I'm not understanding? The `submitConfirmation` method does nothing important, it just sets some internal variables. The form is supposed to submit like a normal HTML form using the action attribute. This was working correctly until I started making changes to implement a new feature so I can assure you the action is definitely being used.

Comment: @altu are you telling me that if I set an `(ngSubmit)` value, this overrides the default form submission entirely?

Comment: I have to apologise if I'm slow on the uptake, I have limited experience with Angular and I inherited this project from another developer :)

Answer (score 0):

the solution is the change the `type` attribute of the button to `button` from `submit`.
The default behavior of the button, when clicked, is to attempt to submit the form to whatever `formaction` is set. Your additional click handler is attempting to override that behavior.

Comment: But I don't even *want* to use that click handler! I only put it there because that's the only way I could make the thing work. It should just be `<button type="submit">` and nothing else, but for some reason when I do that, the form submit handler (`submitConfirmation`) gets called but the form doesn't actually submit

Comment: @JeneralJames any reason you prefer to handle the submit via `[action]` and not in the `(submit)` handler

Comment: To be honest I didn't write this code, I'm just trying to implement a new feature on top of it. The only reason I can think of is that this form actually 'submits to' an iframe. It's an online payment feature where the hosted payment page is rendered inside the iframe. The `[action]` is actually the URL of the payment provider.

Comment: The real form also contains `target="my_iframe"` but I omitted this from the question for brevity

Comment: @JeneralJames How does the form behave without the `submit` handler set?

Comment: I did try that, I removed the `(ngSubmit)` and expected the form to behave "normally" after that but actually it didn't submit at all. It was as if the submit button click was being ignored.

Comment: @JeneralJames a possible solution is to try and get a reference to the iframe and programmatically submit the form